# Intel x86 Assembly Code - Int is not add correctly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, addition

I am building a simple program that takes users numbers and prints the combined total of the numbers. The only problem is the combined total is always a very large number, not even close to the numbers entered. Can anyone spot the problem? The addition takes place in the positive function! Thanks, James

```
int main(void)
{
    char welcome[] = "Comp 103 Assignment 1 - James Austin\n\n";
    char loopNum[] = "How many times would you like to loop? ";
    char get1[] = "Enter a number: ";
    char posTotal[] = "\nPositive Total: ";
    char negTotal[] = "\nNegative Total: ";
    char format[] = "%d";
    char printFormat[] = "\n%d";

    int first;
    int j;
    int posAmount = 0;
    int negAmount = 0;

    _asm{   lea eax,welcome
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp,4

            lea eax, loopNum
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp,4 

            lea eax,first
            push eax
            lea eax,format
            push eax
            call scanf_s
            add esp,8

            mov ecx, first
        Lj: push ecx
            lea eax, get1
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 4

            lea eax, j
            push eax
            lea eax, format
            push eax
            call scanf_s
            add esp, 8

            cmp first,0
            jg positive
            jl negative
    backin : pop ecx
            loop Lj

            lea eax, posTotal
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 4

            lea eax, posAmount
            push eax
            lea eax, format
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 8

            lea eax, negTotal
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 4

            lea eax, negAmount
            push eax
            lea eax, format
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 8

            jmp finish

   positive : mov eax, posAmount
            add eax, j
            mov posAmount, eax
            jmp backin

   negative : mov eax, negAmount
            add eax, first
            mov negAmount, eax
            jmp backin
            finish :
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified any of the following: it is reading in values correctly?  Adding them correctly?

Comment: Checked neither, I will check now

Comment: In one place you use `printf` with `"%d"` as the format string, and _the address of_ `posAmount` as the second argument (you also do the same thing for `negAmount`). Is that intentional (if so, what is its purpose)?

Comment: Its not. I am really confused to why this is not working. I have friends with exactly the same code that is working fine and I really can't see what I am doing different. I tested the numbers, input is fine but when it gets to positive it just keeps printing the same number.

Comment: Well, try printing the values located at `posAmount` and `negAmount` instead of the addresses of those variables.

Comment: I could actually kiss you right now :) ! Thank you so much